# How to professionally express a desire to relocate?

Tags: verbs, phrases

I want to start applying to jobs in the UK, and in my cover letter I wish to include my desire to relocate.

What would be a preferred way of wording this?

> I'm XYZ, looking to relocate to ABC this summer.
>
> I'm XYZ, wishing to relocate to ABC this summer.
>
> I'm XYZ, wanting to relocate to ABC this summer.

Which version would be best suited in a professional setting? Or should I use a different verb/phrase altogether?

Comment: You can find answers here, http://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/13144/how-can-i-best-indicate-my-desire-to-relocate-to-another-part-of-the-country

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Say, "I'm XYZ, willing to relocate to ABC," or "I'm XYZ, willing to consider relocation to ABC."

In my opinion, *willing* sounds more like you are considering relocating for the company's benefit and not yours, which may sound slightly more attractive to someone considering you for a position.

Comment: Could you add an explanation to your answer to say why those two options are preferable?